# How can I use integer division operator "/" in groovy?

Tags: java, groovy

I was migrating a java project to groovy. Then I got an **if** condition is giving `false` in Groovy which was giving `true` in Java code.

### Groovy Sample Code:

```
int status_num = 301
if (status_num / 100 == 3) {
    throw new GoogleServiceConditionException("Google Search System is under maintenance")
}
```

The if condition is giving false for groovy. For Java, it gives true.

How can I mitigate the issue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have searched over Groovy documentation. It say's like below:

> For integer division like in Java, you should use the **intdiv()** method,
>   as Groovy doesn’t provide a dedicated integer division operator
>   symbol.

So, I have changed the code like below.

```
if (status_num.intdiv(100) == 3) {
    throw new GoogleServiceConditionException("Google Search System is under maintenance")
}
```

Now, it works fine.

For more, you can go through the tutorial:  [The case of the division operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-syntax.html#integer_division)